# Iterating and processing HashMap for millions of data

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, hashmap

I have been asked for iterating and processing HashMap having custom object , say Employee as key and employee's age as value. If Map holds millions of data, how is performance and what is the way of optimizing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080370/hashmap-in-java-100-million-entries

Comment: How many entries do you have? and what kind of processing do you want to perform?

Comment: Have a look at MapDB (http://www.mapdb.org/). I have tested it with only few Hundred thousands records but performance was great for my use case.