# Need an optimised Map(k,v) e.g. (long, long[]), to avoid auto boxing

Tags: java, generics, autoboxing, fastutil, koloboke

I have a piece of code which is basically as followed:

```
long[]   ids;
long[][] values;
```

The values are filled out of turn i.e.
`if ids = ['id1','id2',...]`
the values maybe be 
`values = [['id2val1','id2val2',..]['id1val1','id2val2',...],..]`
The out of turn execution cannot be avoided, the approach I am considering is to use a Map
`Map<Long,Long[]>`, 
 but due to auto boxing of java it is not possible use the JAVA generics.

I would like to know if it can be done via some optimised data structure library that uses primitives,
to avoid the unnecessary auto boxing, I am looking at libraries like `Koloboke` & `Fastutil`.
Looking for a data structure recommendation

Comment: Please provide some code to explain what _due to auto boxing of java it is not possible use the JAVA generics_ means.

Comment: @AndrewS - The current code stores time series data.
so the `id[]` contains list of unique identifiers. For each of those there is an associated long array.
Currently it is done via two individual arrays, i.e. ids[],values[][].
However now the results can return out of order so need a way to correlate and access id with value[]. This if done with `Map<Long, Long[]>` takes more time/ processing due to unboxing boxing from long to Long and reverse. So need an optimised data structure, does that clarify the doubt ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726286/map-alternative-for-primitive-values

Comment: Do you know that you _need_ to optimise this?  i.e. is this bottle-necking your software? 
 How large are those data structures?

Comment: @stridecolossus - provided the answers inline 

Do you know that you need to optimise this?
Yes this needs to be as optimised as possible.

Is this bottle-necking your software?
Currently, this is not in use, however this is part of an effort to increase scale.
It would definitely be considered as a bottle-neck 

How large are those data structures ?
Currently average size of the long[][] of values is [1000000][2000]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have to use boxed `Long` as the map key, you do not need to box the primitives in value arrays.  You can use `Map<Long,long[]>` rather than `Map<Long,Long[]>`.  This should alleviate most of your performance concerns.

So, before you start introducing third party libraries, see if simple `HashMap<Long,long[]>` will be good enough for your purposes.