# java map that can be used best for huge concurrent operation

Tags: java, performance

Which Map to be used in Java  for huge concurrent operation in web service like 100 hit per second.
Performance also in consideration.

Comment: yes as @LukeLee suggested 100 isn't huge. if there are no duplicates consider using treemap.

Comment: around 300 update needed at map per/sec, so for that also treemap is fine?

Comment: How many items in your map ? do you add/remove a lot or do yyou mainly find items ?

Answer (score 0):

**java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap** should do the job.

- it is thread safe without synchronizing the whole map
- reads can happen very fast while write is done with a lock
- there is no locking at the object level.

If you plan to process a huge amount of data, you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757363/java-hashmap-performance-optimization-alternative) for more informations.

Comment: around 300 update needed at map per/sec, so for that also ConcurrentHashMap is fine

Comment: It should be fine

Answer (score 0):

yes,100 is not huge.Huge concurrent operation u should use ConcurrentHashMap and learn more about current package.

Comment: around 300 update needed at map per/sec, so for that also ConcurrentHashMap  is fine?

Answer (score 0):

For such load, you can either go for ConcurrentHashMap or SynchronizedMap.

But I would say if you look from a scalability perspective (If the loads can increase in the future), I would recommend to use a ConcurrentHashMap.

And also in ConcurrentHashMap, the locking is not on the entire map level. Instead it is at the block level (block can be single key or a set of keys).

Please refer http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-concurrenthashmap-works-in-java-internal-implementation.html for more information on ConcurrentHashMap internal working.